# SELECT INTO output parameter when no rows are returned?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Given something like the following, where `ID` is the primary key,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
 @ID INT,
 @RetVal INT OUT
AS BEGIN
 Select @RetVal = Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID;
END
```

What happens if no row exists with the specified primary key (`ID`)? Will I get a failure or will @RetVal be left in an unspecified state?

Additionally, how can the caller of the procedure know this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable (or parameter in this case) will have whatever value it had before and no assignment is made.

If the caller of the procedure isn't passing anything else in explicitly as a value to the parameter then this will be `null` in your case.

You can check `@@rowcount` immediately after the statement to see how many rows were involved. If 0 no assignment is made, if more than 1 it is undeterministic which of the possible values was actually assigned.

You can rewrite as follows to assign null (overwriting any existing value) if zero rows matched and throw an error if more than one did.

```
 Set  @RetVal = (SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID);
```

Also see this recent answer on the DBA site [Where do this Constant Scan and Left Outer Join come from in a trivial SELECT query plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136210/where-do-this-constant-scan-and-left-outer-join-come-from-in-a-trivial-select-qu/136212#136212)

Comment: And if @Retval was unassigned, it will return `NULL`.